# referencing node modules from a local folder

Tags: node.js, npm

Due to proxy restrictions on my office system, for installation of node and its modules I  depended on a outside PC. I have **node.exe** and **npm.cmd** in my external system and I was able to download modules there

> npm install express

I copied the node_modules folder from my external PC and placed it in my node installed path in my office PC, but still I was not able to do

> require ('express')

It says module express not found.* 
So then I thought node is not considering this module as installed so I copied the module folder near my project and in one of my js file I introduced a path variable.

> var path  = 'D:/sw/nodejs/'; // here i copied the express folder for the time being
>   var express = require(path+'express'),    app = express.createServer();

Here while running I get module 'connect' not found.

Where should I place these dependent modules, to have them work correctly and 
can't we install modules of node by pasting them in node_modules ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `NODE_PATH` variable in your environment

```
set NODE_PATH=D:/sw/nodejs/node_modules
```

Then you can use all modules inside `D:/sw/nodejs/node_modules`. express requires connect module which it cannot find with `require('connect')`, unlike express which you call by `require(path+'express')`.

You can also specify multiple paths in NODE_PATH delimited by ';'

```
set NODE_PATH=C:/path/1;C:/path/2;
```

It would be better to set one than type it every time on console. Go to :
My Computer > Right-click > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > New
and set the variable `NODE_PATH` there. You will have to restart to see the changes.

Comment: After this configuration, is there a way to add used modules to dependencies on package.json automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Put the downloaded packages into a `node_modules` folders on the **root** (from where you call node) of you project / source code.
- [Set up](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html) a proxy for npm. ([Example](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy))

Comment: if you read my question correctly, i have mentioned doing, what you just answered

Comment: @sij I wasn't aware that you have tried the proxy approach. I also wanted to show that module not not have to installed globally on the $NODE_PATH and instead could live within your project